# Flask form submit both succeeds and errors

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask form which works perfect and stores values in my database, but it seems to both succeed (posts values to the database and shows success flash) and fails (shows error and doesn't redirect).

view.py

```
from flask import render_template, Blueprint, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from project import db
from .models import Items
from .forms import ItemsForm


items_blueprint = Blueprint('items', __name__, template_folder='templates')


@items_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def all_items():
    all_user_items = Items.query.filter_by()
    return render_template('all_items.html', items=all_user_items)


@items_blueprint.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_item():
    form = ItemsForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                new_item = Items(form.name.data, form.notes.data)
                db.session.add(new_item)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('Item added', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('all_items'))
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
                flash('Something went wrong', 'error')
    return render_template('add_item.html', form=form)
```

Output Example

[image]

What might be causing this, as I thought it would be one or the other.

Comment: An error in the `redirect` will cause this, the "Item added" is already flashed. As an aside, **never** code a bare except. You do not know what you catch.

Comment: Can you expect on the redirect error please? The redirect never seems to happen as it stays on the same page.

Comment: As I said: **never** code a bare except. Remove the whole `try: .. except:` construct, start Flask in debug mode and you will find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it because of the @NoCommandLine answer. The point is, that the `all_items` function is located in the blueprint, not in the base of the application. To redirect to it you want to write `redirect(url_for(".all_items")` (notice the full stop at the first position of the string).See [the documentation for `url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=url_for#flask.url_for), there is an example for a blueprint containing an `index` function. The full stop makes it search in the same blueprint the current route is in.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on where the error occurred. Since it flashed - `('Item added', 'success')`, it means your error is on the line `redirect(url_for('all_items'))`.

You should look at the code for `redirect(url_for('all_items'))` and check if there is an issue with `all_user_items = Items.query.filter_by()`. Maybe that query is faulty. You can also try to print out the error in the `except` block to see what it is